Number Of Planning Attempts MoveIt
I am using moveit to plan robot trajectory, since sometimes it can not be able to find any solution or the solution that provides is weird, I want to increase the planning attempts in such a way it gives me the best solution. I am using "pilz_industrial_motion_planner" as pipeline.
I am writing from a python code and the trajectory is computed using the Ros Service GetMotionSequence (http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/moveit_msgs/html/srv/GetMotionSequence.html).
The request message is a list of MotionSequenceItem (http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/MotionSequenceItem.html). One of the properties of that message is num_attempts, setting the values it seems that it ignore it, the computational time remains the same even if i put huge values, like 10^6.
